# Text value from an array displayed on a div

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have being wandering around this but can't make it work. I am getting a text value from an array on `localStorage` but I am failing with the easy part, display this value on a `div`.

This is my code:

javascript

```
function loadLastSell() {
var contacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("f7Contacts")) || {};
for (var k = 0; k < contacts.length; k++) {
var Sellings = contacts[k].sellings;
}console.log(Sellings);
var sellings = Sellings;
for (var x = 0; x < sellings.length; x++) {
var lselling = document.getElementById("lselling");
var lSelling = sellings[x].vdate;
}console.log(lSelling);
}
```

html

```
<div class="item-title">Fecha de confección:</div>
    <div class="item-inner">
        <div class="item-subtitle" id="lselling"></div>
    </div>
```

This is the debuging result:

[image: Debuging]

But I can't manage to display the text value on the div as shown in this image:

[image: div image]

What I want is to get the last element of the array and display it on the `div`. My code is working but I can't manage to diplay the element on the `div`. I need to get the last object withing `sellings` and display the value of `vdate` on `#lselling`. Just that. `console.log(lSelling);` is showing `19/03/2023 05:34 AM`, and this is what I want to be displayed there. I'm already within a `contact`, now I need to get the last `selling` of this contact and display the value of `vdate`.

What's wrong within my code?

**UPDATE**

For future askers I solved it turning the function to `async` just like this:

```
async function loadLastSell() {
var contacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("f7Contacts")) || {};
for (var k = 0; k < contacts.length; k++) {
var Sellings = contacts[k].sellings;
}
var sellings = Sellings;
for (var x = 0; x < sellings.length; x++) {
await 2;
lselling = document.getElementById("lselling")
lSelling = sellings[x].vdate;
}
lselling.innerHTML = lSelling
}
```

Now the value of `vdate` last `selling` ise properly displayed on the `div`.

Comment: Please do not show images of code

Comment: Also you set contacts to an object if it does not exist in localStorage - is it an object?

Comment: You seem to just repeatedly reassign `Sellings` in your first loop so it will only hold the last element of the array by the end. You then try to use a `for` loop on the `length` of that element which is an object with no length so nothing is displayed as the loop never runs.

Comment: I don't get the sense of your comments, can you explain them, please?

Comment: That's because it is an object and not an array, so you can't iterate over it using a `for` loop. You can do this in two lines: `const sellings = contacts[contacts.length - 1]; document.getElementById("lselling").innerText = sellings.vdate;`

Comment: @pilchard, that's precisely what I want, to get the last element of the array and display it on the `div`. My code is working but I can't manage to diplay the element on the `div`. I need to get the last object withing `sellings` and display the value of `vdate` on   `#lselling`. Just that. `console.log(lSelling);` is showing `19/03/2023 05:34 AM`, and this is what I want to be displayed there.

Comment: @pilchard, if I use `const sellings = contacts[contacts.length - 1];` I will get the last item of `f7Contacts`, and that's not what I want. I'm already within a `contact`, now I need to get the last `selling` of this `contact` and display the value of `vdate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I get it you already have the text value stored in the "lSelling" var.
And the "lselling" var keeps the div you want to show this text in.

To put your text into the div, you may use "innerHTML" as an option:

```
// ...
for (var x = 0; x < sellings.length; x++) {
var lselling = document.getElementById("lselling");
var lSelling = sellings[x].vdate;
}console.log(lSelling);
// putting your var into the innerHTML of the div:
lselling.innerHTML = lSelling
}
```

In fact, you don't need the loop there, can be written like:

```
const isellingElm = document.getElementById("lselling");
const lastSelling = sellings[sellings.length - 1];
isellingElm.innerHTML = lastSelling.vdate;
```

UPD:
For the JS code to work, it has to be executed after the HTML content is loaded.
The easiest for this is placing the  tag after the lselling div:

```
<script>
// FAIL: your div is not the part of the document yet
loadLastSell();
</script>

<div class="item-title">Fecha de confección:</div>
<div class="item-inner">
  <div class="item-subtitle" id="lselling"></div>
</div>

<script>
// CORRECT: will be executed after the content is loaded
loadLastSell();
</script>
```

Comment: I get this `Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "innerHTML", lselling is null`

Comment: Could be, yes, if you execute the JS code before the HTML is rendered.
The easiest to solve it is to put the "script" tag after the HTML, updated the response to have it with formatting

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where to locate the script as it is an MVC app and it's a little bit complicated to load the script after the  HTML is fully rendered, or, at least, it's being for me. I'll keep on touch!!!

Comment: following your advice I tried to make the script to run after the HTLM was fully rendered and I finally realized the only way to do it was to turn the `function` to an `async function` and it works perfectly. Thanks. Update your question so I can vote it as the accepted one. Could you please?

Comment: @SIMBIOSISsurl don't know how updating the answer can help accepting it... Can it be you tried to vote it up instead of accepting (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Answer (score -1):

Your loop contents are wrong

```
var Sellings = contacts[k].sellings;
```

is setting the same var over and over

This is wrong:

```
var lselling = document.getElementById("lselling");
var lSelling = sellings[x].vdate;
```

you replace lSelling over and over and do not update the content of the lselling element. Also very poor choice of names lselling (element) and lSelling (value)

You might have more luck with this assuming my testdata looks like your data. If not show an example of the data instead of a picture of it

I have used the optional/conditional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `.?` and the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) `??` to give a "No sales" if vdate is missing

```js
//const contacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("f7Contacts")) || [];
const listSelling = document.getElementById("lselling");

const loadLastSell = () => {
  listSelling.innerHTML = contacts
    .map(contact => `<div class="contact">
      ${contact.sellings
        .map(selling => `<span class="date">${new Date(selling.vdate).toLocaleDateString()}</span>`).join("<br/>")}
    </div>`).join("");
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",loadLastSell);
```

```css
.contact { padding:2px; border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div id="lselling"></div>

<script>
// testdata
const contacts = [{
    "sellings": [{
        vdate: "2022-03-20",
        "pdcb": "A"
      },
      {
        vdate: "2022-03-21",
        "pdcb": "B"
      },
      {
        vdate: "2022-03-22",
        "pdcb": "C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sellings": [{
      vdate: "2022-03-24",
      "pdcb": "D"
    }, ]
  },
  {
    "sellings": [{
      vdate: "2022-03-25",
      "pdcb": "E"
    }, ]
  },

];</script>
```

If you only want to show the last one:

```js
//const contacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("f7Contacts")) || [];
const listSelling = document.getElementById("lselling");

const loadLastSell = () => {
  listSelling.innerHTML = contacts
    .map(contact => `<div class="contact">${contact.sellings[contact.sellings.length-1]?.vdate ?? "No sales"}</div>`).join("");
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",loadLastSell);
```

```css
.contact { padding:2px; border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div id="lselling"></div>

<script>
// testdata
const contacts = [{
    "sellings": [{
        vdate: "2022-03-20",
        "pdcb": "A"
      },
      {
        vdate: "2022-03-21",
        "pdcb": "B"
      },
      {
        vdate: "2022-03-22",
        "pdcb": "C"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sellings": [{
      vdate: "2022-03-24",
      "pdcb": "D"
    }, ]
  },
  {
    "sellings": [{
      /* Missing vdate */
      "pdcb": "E"
    }, ]
  },

];</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You are not working with `lselling` anywhere. You are getting the element with `getElementById` and then just reasigning the variable `lselling`. Just do

```js
var lselling = document.getElementById("lselling");
lSelling.textContent = sellings[x].vdate;
```

Btw this code needs tons of optimizations.